# opengl memory leaks tools

Tags: opengl

I saw there are lots of post available but no anyone could resolve issue. I have made a simple game where I used GLUT lib for openGL. I want to see the memory leaks but unfortunate I don't know which tool be easy to use and configure.

The program is written in C++ with glut lib opengl in VC++ 2008 exp. edition.

Comment: Are you looking for tools that tell you when you have failed to clean up OpenGL objects, or just memory leaks in general?

Comment: Have you tried typing `OpenGL debugger` into a search engine? It brings up a lot of useful links.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out gDebugger.  Find it at www.gremedy.com

I also suggest you invest time in learning about detecting memory leaks in c++.  There are lots of tools out there, but start with [memory leak detection using the c runtime libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Good luck!